# Azure data factory- Azure function to connect sql database does not work

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity in ADF. On completion I wanted to update a table. 
Stored proc is not an option for us. 
Would like to know all other options to run the update query post copy.
Tried Azure function to connect to sql database and update the table. 
Works fine separately with time trigger . 
What trigger to be used for the Azure function for this scenario in ADF?

Thanks in advance,
Aruna

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want to execute a function to update a table after a copy activity and you don't want to use time trigger. Currently Azure function supported as a step in Azure Data Factory pipelines. So we just need to drag the azure function to pipeline in Azure Data Factory and provide the info of your function(such as the name, url...).

[image]

For further information, you can refer to this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am aware of Azure function being supported in ADF. I also wrote a time trigger azure function to connect to sql database. I get the below error when called after copy activity                                                                                          Call to provided Azure function '' failed with status-'NotFound' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.                       
 What trigger to be used while creating azure function?

Comment: Hi @ArunaJayabalu, I think we should use http trigger, could you please share some details of your function and I will try to find why it shows "HttpStatusCode - NotFound".

Comment: Below is the Azure function code. This get executed successfully  seperately in the portal. But when I map this function with the url I get error.

Comment: @ArunaJayabalu, you can post your code or screenshot in your question. Just click "edit" and add the screenshot in it or wrap the code up with ```

Comment: public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,ILogger log)
{
            var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var text = "UPDATE sometable "
                }}

Comment: Hi @ArunaJayabalu, your code shows you still use time tirgger. You need to create another function in your azure portal and use http trigger. Then write the code(for update table) in it. Please refer to this tutorial to know how to create a http trigger in azure function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function

Comment: Hi @ArunaJayabalu, may I know if your issue was solved ? If solved, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks. If the issue hasn't been solved, please let me know.

Comment: yes sorry for the late reply. Issue got resolved based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-a-round: within lookup you can define a sql query and execute quiete a lot of logic. There is a limit of ~2MB of data returned on the lookup (not listed as a limitation of ADF).